# css media queries working with firefox "device test modes", but not in responsive test websites

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, media-queries, mobile-devices

im creating a bunch css media queries for specific mobile devices, when I test it with the developer tools in firefox that mimic those devices, the website shows right. But if I go for example to "http://www.infobyip.com/testwebsiteresolution.php" and test the website, the media queries are completely ignored.

Notice im working in localhost. Any insight would be helpful.

the media queries im using are:

```
/* ----------- Galaxy S5 ----------- */
/* Portrait and Landscape */
@media screen and (device-width: 360px) and (device-height: 640px) {

#nsp-equipo .nspArt h4.nspHeader a{ font-size:21px; top:56px; }

#nsp-equipo p.nspText{ top:-106px; font-size:14px; }

#nsp-equipo a.readon{
top:-110px;
right:25px;
padding: 6px 30px;
font-size:12px; 
}

}

/* ----------- iPhone 6 ----------- */
/* Landscape Only */
@media screen and (min-device-width: 375px) and (max-device-width: 667px) and (orientation: landscape) {

#nsp-equipo .nspArt h4.nspHeader a{ font-size:20px; top:54px; float:right; }

#nsp-equipo p.nspText{ top:-111px; font-size:14px; }

#nsp-equipo a.readon{ 
font-size: 12px;
padding: 5px 30px;
top:-120px;
right:23px; 
}

#nsp-equipo div.nspArtPage div.nspArt{ height:180px;}

}

/* ----------- iPhone 6+ ----------- */
/* Portrait */
@media screen and (min-device-width: 414px) and (max-device-width: 736px) and (orientation: portrait) {

#nsp-equipo p.nspText{ top:-125px;}

#nsp-equipo a.readon{
top:-130px;
right:34px; 
}

#nsp-equipo div.nspArtPage div.nspArt{ height:210px;}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your media queries are testing device-width — the width of the screen, not the window. Change them to use `min-width` and `max-width`.

Comment: That was pretty straight-forward!, it works now. Do you think i should keep the "device" tag for the mobiles or is it better to just set them with width and height?

Comment: No; device-width/height don't seem useful for what you're doing. (Actually I'm not sure what they are useful for.)

Comment: You got me googling...found this  " In general width is more versatile when it comes to creating responsive webpages, though device-width is useful when you wish to specifically target mobile devices (and not desktops with a small browser window for example), as rarely do desktops have screen resolutions below a certain number such as 320px x 480px."  http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/cssmediaqueries2.shtml